# Entity Framework is not inserting the composite key I specified

Tags: entity-framework

Can someone shed light onto this?
I have three objects. Firstly, a Root object

```
public class Root
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is the basis for my composite key, used in Parent,Child:

```
public class Parent 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RootId { get; set; }
    public Root Root { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; } = new Collection<Child>();

}

public class Child
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RootId { get; set; }
    public Root Root { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RootId, ParentId")]
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I add a new parent object with multiple children

```
Parent result = new Parent 
{
    RootId = rootId
};

foreach (var child in children)
{
    result.Children.Add(new Child
    {
        RootId = rootId
    });
}

_dbContext.Parents.Add(result);
_dbContext.Save();
```

However, I get an exception whenever I have *multiple Root objects* in my database:

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Children_dbo.Parents_RootId_ParentId". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.Parents".`

When I delete the foreign key constraint in my database, I can see that EF is somehow ignoring the `RootId = rootId` that I set. It uses a different one instead. The ParentId is correctly set, but obviously this results in a FK that doesn't exist.

I want to commit the parent and its children in one Save call. I've tried adding the children to _dbContext.Children after adding the parent to _dbContext.Parents, I've tried first adding the Children, to no avail.

Can someone shed light on this? I'm running out of ideas on what to check to understand what I'm doing wrong..

Edit: I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3.

Comment: What's the content of the `children` variable? Also, add the property `Children` to your `Parent` class in the question and show which EF version you're using.

Comment: @GertArnold, EF 6.1.3, updated parent class pseudocode in my question. The `children` variable is a list of objects containing some other data, such as string, decimal and optional int. Seems totally irrelevant here.

Comment: It works for me as soon as `rootId` is a valid `Id` of an existing (in db) `Root` entity - does that apply to your case?

Comment: @IvanStoev The Root entity is valid and exists (saved) in the database in my test.

Comment: Then check your real code. With the sample model/code the issue cannot be reproduced - everything works as expected.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your reply and checking the sample. Do you happen to have any suggestions on what I can double check? Because the real code in essence does not differ from the sample.

Comment: Eventually if the `Id` column in `Parent` table in database is actually identity. Turn the context logging on (for instance, `_dbContext.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;`), then try again. Normally you should see `INSERT` in `Parent` followed by `SELECT` retrieving the `Id`. Then several `INSERT` in `Child` with `rootId, parentId`. At the time of exception you can see the failed command and parameters.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for that! I found that you're right, it's elsewhere: I had one additional FK dependency and THAT object had the wrong reference to Root. It caused the Child.RootId to be coerced to that value :( Thank you so much for the log tip, so immensely useful